# What is "icdd" and why is it persistent?

Tags: macos, launchd

I have a relatively older Macbook Air (late 2010).  Memory usage is pretty tight on it, and I try to keep things as svelte as possible in that regards.

Lately, I've noticed the process `icdd` is using up about 50 MB (doesn't seem like much unless you only have 2000 to spare).  According to Activity Monitor, it's from Image Capture, but I don't use that program, and there is no image-related activity that requires daemon activity on my computer as iPhoto's preference on what to do with a camera is set to "do nothing" and I don't use Image Capture or iPhoto —ever— on this laptop.

So what, exactly, is "icdd" and why is it persistent when its associated programs are never run on this machine?  Can it be safely deleted or otherwise inactivated (modifying launchagents)?

Comment: Its location would confirm your theory `/System/Library/Image Capture/Support/icdd` I can only assume that it's the background process responsible for launching Photos etc on connecting a camera/phone, but I can't find any corroborating evidence.

Comment: Check this answer out:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258323/icdd-process-consuming-substantial-memory-on-macos/270484#270484