# Function of a particular process in macOS High Sierra! (PrintUITool)

Tags: mac, macos, imac, activity-monitor

What is the significance of this (PrintUITool) process which goes by the name of PrintUITool, I cam across this process in activity monitor and found it take up huge chunks of memory and CPU space of my mac. I want to know what is the importance of this process and what happens if I remove it from my mac

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258323/icdd-process-consuming-substantial-memory-on-macos

Comment: @JMY1000 This doesn't answers my question!

Comment: I know :/ Thought it might be useful to take a look anyways though since it's the same issue with more discussion.